# How to display labels of pie charts for top 5 highes percentage only

Tags: javascript, laravel, amcharts

How to display the labels of the top 5 highest percent slice in pie charts.
I also want to know how to access each data in target.dataItem.values individually to compare it and get my 6 largest data the return it on my pie chart.

**I've tried,**

```java
//Enabling 6 largest industry on the outer circle
pieSeries[i].ticks.template.adapter.add("hidden", hideSmall);
pieSeries[i].labels.template.adapter.add("hidden", hideSmall);

function hideSmall(hidden, target) {
    return target.dataItem.values.value.value < num ? true : false;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "hidden" is used for another purposes, try to use "opacity" or "disabled"

Comment: I want to know how to access the target item individually so I can compare who has the top 5 largest value and display those 5 as labels in the pie chart.